# Camera view goes crazy to another view

Tags: rendering, camera

I am trying to change the render from a different point of view and is almost impossible. I have this 
[image]

and pressing <kbd>0</kbd>  and I obtain this
[image]

and everything I do this is not going to change.
I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> and I have the same view but the object rotates far away.
I use blender 2.8.

Is there a way to tell Blender to render this camera from this view?

The file is available here if someone wants to have a look
https://github.com/acipolla/casa-dedo

Comment: could you link the blend file?

Comment: I'm learning this stuff, please have mercy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you set the Plane as a local camera here. So every time you pressed 0 key it, blender showed you the local camera set as the plane and thus you were seeing the inside of the washing machine.[image]

Just deselect the "Use Local Camera" checkbox, that would allow you to change the Local Camera. Select the camera of you scene using the eye dropper tool or by the list.
[image]

and now when you press the 0 key, it will show what you camera is looking at.[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Harshvardhan Rajpurohit! Your answer was very helpful!!